# Moving SP from dev to production

Tags: 2013, development, production

So I am completely new to SharePoint (and SQL) and I have been tasked with creating a brand new intranet for our company where the dev and production areas were set up before I arrived.

I am currently at a stage where I want to migrate my development version to the production server and I am running into troubles. I have tried backing it up and restoring it (in a shared folder in the production sql server) to the new Sp server however it keeps on running into SQL exception errors on various items (wss_content, metadata, etc):

***sqlexception***: The operation did not proceed far enough to allow RESTART. Reissue the statement without the RESTART qualifier. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I believe this may be due to the fact that the dev server is a single server (sql and Sp on the same machine) while the production is split into two servers SQL, SP and that is causing the errors on restores.

**My Question**: Am I right or (as I have seen around the internet) that the above exception is thrown because of permission errors on the share folder? If I am right which db's do I need to move and how do I do so?

For the record I am using SP 2013, SQL 2013, all servers are windows server 2012.
My SharePoint Site has so far been completely made through SP and SPD.

Comment: How did you back it up? Did you use Backup-SPSite and then Restore-SPSite?

Comment: I went through CA backup/restore and made a back up of the entire farm. 

Since I have posted this question I have (or more accurately the admin of the server) has moved the data bases for me however now I get upgrade errors while trying to do a restore through CA even though to the best of my knowledge the versions of SP are exactly the same (servers were set up on the same day). I have a feeling with the db moved across a restore isn't needed is that right?

Comment: In your situation all you need backed up is your site collection. There is no need to do a farm backup and restore. Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for that I thought I was missing something really obvious. However now with sp-restore I am getting this error

Restore-SPSite : The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type..

Apparently it is due to web.config nodes being duplicated however when I checked my web application config files (_wpresources & wpresources web.config files) they don't have any duplicated nodes.

Comment: Do you have a working site collection in your destination farm?

Comment: No when I make a site collection it comes up with a 500 error when I try to access it

Comment: I've gotten the new server to be restored to state before I have touched it so hopefully that helps.

Also this 5 minute time limit for edits is annoying

Comment: Thanks Bunzab you were a great help! It works fine now. I must have messed something up while do failed farm restores and IIS settings. If you want put in a 'proper' answer and I'll mark it as the answer